# Testing Material UI components using Hooks API & Enzyme shallow rendering

Tags: material-ui, enzyme, react-hooks

The latest versions of Material UI now have a Hooks alternative for styling components, instead of the HoC. So instead of

```
const styles = theme => ({
  ...
});

export const AppBarHeader = ({ classes, title }) => (
  ...
);
export default withStyles(styles)(AppBarHeader);
```

you can choose to do this instead:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  xxxx
}));

const AppBarHeader = ({ title }) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    ....
  )
};

export default AppBarHeader;
```

In some ways this is nicer, but as with all hooks you can no longer inject a 'stub' dependency to the component. Previously, for testing with Enzyme I just tested the non-styled component:

```
describe("<AppBarHeader />", () => {
  it("renders correctly", () => {
    const component = shallow(
      <AppBarHeader title="Hello" classes="{}" />
    );
    expect(component).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

However, if you use hooks, without the 'stub' dependency for classes, and you get:

```
  Warning: Material-UI: the `styles` argument provided is invalid.
  You are providing a function without a theme in the context.
  One of the parent elements needs to use a ThemeProvider.
```

because you always need a provider in place. I can go and wrap this up:

```
describe("<AppBarHeader />", () => {
  it("renders correctly", () => {
    const component = shallow(
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <AppBarHeader title="Hello" classes="{}" />
      </ThemeProvider>
    ).dive();
    expect(component).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

but that no longer seems to render the children of the component (even with the dive call). How are folks doing this?

Comment: It seems the answer is (a) don't do shallow renders and (b) use react-testing-library rather than Enzyme

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: As per the comments below, this implementation presents some timing issues. Consider testing with mount instead of shallow testing, or use the `withStyles` HOC and export your component for shallow rendering.

So I have been grappling with this for a day now. Here is what I have come up with.

There are some issues trying to stub `makeStyles` since it appears MUI has made it readonly. So instead of creating a `useStyles` hook in each component, I created my own custom `useStyles` hook that calls `makeStyles`. In this way I can stub my `useStyles` hook for testing purposes, with minimal impact to the flow of my code.

```
// root/utils/useStyles.js
// My custom useStyles hook

import makeStyles from '@material-ui/styles/makeStyles';

export const useStyles = styles => makeStyles(theme => styles(theme))();
```

Its almost like using the `withStyles` HOC

```
// root/components/MyComponent.js
import React from 'react';
import { useStyles } from '../util/useStyles';

// create styles like you would for withStyles
const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    padding: 0,
  },
});

export const MyComponent = () => {
  const classes = useStyles(styles);
  return(
    </>
  );
}
```

```
// root/component/MyComponent.spec.js
import { MyComponent } from './MyComponent';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import { stub } from 'sinon';

describe('render', () => {
  it('should render', () => {
    let useStylesStub;
    useStylesStub = stub(hooks, 'useStyles');
    useStylesStub.returns({ });
    const wrapper = shallow(<MyComponent />);
    console.log('profit');
  });
});
```

This is the best I can come up with for now, but always open to suggetions.

Comment: This approach is problematic. `makeStyles` is intended to be called once per styles object, but with your approach it will be called once per render. Each render will use a new version of the custom hook returned by `makeStyles`. This will also negatively affect the order of the style sheet generated (see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57220059/internal-implementation-of-makestyles-in-react-material-ui/57226057#57226057) for explanation). You would be much better off to use `withStyles` than to use this approach.

Comment: Also see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56929702/material-ui-v4-makestyles-exported-from-a-single-file-doesnt-retain-the-styles/56941531#56941531) for further insight into the problems this approach will cause.

Comment: Thanks for the update, I was worried this would cause issues

Comment: useEffect will not have the appropriate timing to manage this correctly. My recommendation is to change the testing approach to not use shallow rendering as @JamesCrowley mentioned in his comment rather than doing weird workarounds in your code.

Comment: Could one not just memoize the `useStyles` to solve the re-render issues?

Comment: The timing of `makeStyles` will still be off. For the interaction between parent and child component styles to work appropriately, `makeStyles` should be called when the component is imported rather than when it is rendered.